# Tkinter code Works in Windows but not in Mac

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

Why does the following test not display the menu on my Mac running Python 3.7 on Mojave?

Tried a shebang but that didn't help.

```
import tkinter as tk

def quit_app():
    my_window.destroy()

    my_window = tk.Tk()
    my_menu = tk.Menu(my_window)
    my_menu.add_command(label='Quit',command=quit_app)
    my_window.config(menu=my_menu)
    my_window.mainloop()
```

The menu displays in Windows 10 but not on the Mac. The tkinter window is blank on the Mac.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/52529403/3001761?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read through the "How to ask a good question" section before asking a question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Please consider giving a better title/question heading. Also please be careful of duplicating questions, search for similar questions before asking one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> The menu displays in Windows 10 but not on the Mac

Yes, that is because MAC has a design philosophy that all devs for their platform have to conform with.
You cannot have a `add_command` as a top level menu item on mac, rather:

```
import tkinter as tk

def quit_app():
    my_window.destroy()

my_window = tk.Tk()
my_menu = tk.Menu(my_window)
quit_menu= tk.Menu(my_menu, tearoff=0)
quit_menu.add_command(label='Quit App',command=quit_app)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Quit", menu=quit_menu, underline=0)
my_window.config(menu=my_menu)
my_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: line 4, in <module>
    quit_menu.add_command(label='Quit App',command=quit_app)
NameError: name 'quit_app' is not defined

Comment: check the updated code format above. You did not define the `quit_app` function.